# MySQL geo search using Python - Tradeoffs and Implementation

Tags: python, mysql

I have an sql table that has some data on retail locations with `lat`, `long` coordinates. My flask application queries the table to pull the data using python.

```
table1

id  name   lat       long
1   post   37.788151 -122.407570
2   sutter 37.789551 -122.408302
3   oak    37.815730 -122.288810
```

I have a point coordinate `37.785980` and `-122.410851`, and I'd like to find rows from the table that are nearby, say within 0.5 mile radius from the coordinate.

Performance matters. I cannot query all rows due to poor performance, long time sending data to client application and storage / memory issues. What would be a efficient way of doing this?

Using SQL in python, how do I implement an efficient solution that does proximity search and returns rows that meet the distance condition? Here's how I pull data from `sql` in `python`.

```
# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'pwd'
host =  'xxxx.1.rds.amazonaws.com'
port = 3306
database = 'db1'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))



# Readdata
con = engine.connect()

query = '''
        SELECT x
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY key
        '''

df = pd.read_sql(query, con)

con.close()
```

Happy to share more info if required for context.

Comment: There is a special column type (`GEOMETRY`), and a special index type (['SPATIAL'](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html)), using R-tree, designed specifically for this purpose

Comment: @Marat would you mind sharing a solution? How do I implement it?